# Check if string contains 2 values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ms-access, pdo

I have a little issue, that i need to solve. In my database, users have names table, fields are like: userID: 1 / Name: firstname / Lastname: lastname. I have a string in file, that i need to verify, string is: "lastname, firstname" How I can verify, that string contain both items?

**What I'm trying:**

```
$fullname = $data[1];
            $showdata = $db->prepare("SELECT userID FROM users WHERE firstname LIKE '%$fullname%' AND lastname LIKE '%$fullname%'");
            $userioID = $rowas['userID'];
            $showdata->execute();
            $rowas= $showdata->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            echo $userioID;
```

**EDIT**

**Database:**
[image]

**FILE**
[image]

Being more specific, one element, which is Talandis, Justinas, In database is like 2 cells. How I can verify, that string in file contains both, first name and lastname?

**EDIT 2**

```
$fullname = $data[1];
            $showdata = $db->prepare("SELECT userID FROM users WHERE lastname + ',' + firstname LIKE '%$fullname%'");
            $showdata->execute();
            $rowas= $showdata->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $userioID = $rowas['userID'];
            echo $userioID;
```

**FINAL EDIT:**

`$showdata = $db->prepare("SELECT userID FROM users WHERE lastname + ', ' + firstname LIKE '%$fullname%'");` - Added space - and it is working.

Comment: Have you tried with regex ?

Comment: Can you be more specific please?

Comment: You have two database engines tagged.  Please remove the inappropriate one.

Comment: why not just `$fullname===$lastname.", ".$firstname`?

Comment: @nonchip Please, tell me how to use it.

Comment: @JustinasT ok, maybe you wanna go back to php basics ;) that's a comparison statement I quoted there, so I guess you'd put it as argument to `if` or whatever you want do to when checking.

Comment: @nonchip the part I do not get is how to extract firstname and lastname from database to compare it with string which is on file :)

Comment: ok, start by executing the query and fetching it's result BEFORE you try to access the variable (`$rowas` is used before defining it). then edit your question which is clearly "check if string contains 2 values", not "how do I get a row from a database"…

Comment: @nonchip in Edit 2 You can see where I am right now. It prints same id on every name - which is incorrect.

Comment: and still you asked a totally different question from what's actually your problem -_-

Comment: Did you try my corrected answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all the strings in the file are the same and as you posted, you can get the desired variables like that:

```
$parts=explode(";",$filestring);
$names=explode(",",$parts[1]);
$lastname=$names[0];
$firstname=$names[1];
```

Then you use you SQL:

```
$showdata = $db->prepare("SELECT userID FROM users WHERE firstname LIKE '%$firstname%' AND lastname LIKE '%$lastname%'")
```

Comment: btw you notice you didn't escape the parameters there? oh and I guess you're missing another explode.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $fullname contains à string like that "Lastname, firstname"preg_match("/([a-zA-Z]*), ([a-zA-Z]*)/",$fullname,$result);

Then $result should be an array :
[
   "Lastname, firstname",
   "Lastname",
   "firstname"
]

Sorry for the format but I'm answering from my phone.

By the way, you can improve it for composed names like jean-francois, etc.